# generate annotated java class from hbm file

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, hbm

I have an old project in which java classes are generated from hbm files.

Is it possible ,using these hbm files, to generate java classes with annotations?

Comment: yes with netbeans i did that , during generation (reverse ingenering) it demande to me if i want to use xml file ou annotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it *directly* from hbm to annotations, but **it's possible to do it** if you proceed like this:

1. Generate the database schema from your hbm configuration.
2. Use [**Hibernate reverse engeneering**](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/reverseengineering.html) to generate annotated classes from this database.

You may take a look at these links for further information:

- [**Generating Hibernate annotated classes from database using eclipse**](https://web.archive.org/web/20150215040630/http://j2eeandeclipsetutorials.blogspot.com/2012/08/generating-hibernate-annotated-classes.html).
- [**How to generate domain objects with annotations using hibernate tools**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878662/how-to-generate-domain-objects-with-annotations-using-hibernate-tools).
- [**How to generate Hibernate mapping files & annotation with Hibernate Tools**](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/)

Answer (score 3):

We have had the same issue and solved it by using this hbm to annotation converter script 
https://github.com/SchweizerischeBundesbahnen/hibernate_hbm2annotation

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [hibernate reverse engeneering tool](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/reverseengineering.html), but for generating annoted classes from database not from hbm's.

Comment: Actually, generated classes aren't annotated at all and  are wrong  in many ways.